# WordPress custom post type - Invalid post type?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Why do I get **Invalid post type** for:

```
function keyword_pages_init() {
    $args = array(
      'label' => 'Keywords',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'keyword'),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-page',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            // 'trackbacks',
            //'custom-fields',
            //'comments',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'author',
            'page-attributes',
            )
        );
    register_post_type( 'keyword', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'keyword_pages_init' );
```

What is gone wrong?

But it is fine with the keyword with a s:

```
function keyword_pages_init() {
    $args = array(
      'label' => 'Keywords',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'keywords'),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-page',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            // 'trackbacks',
            //'custom-fields',
            //'comments',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'author',
            'page-attributes',
            )
        );
    register_post_type( 'keywords', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'keyword_pages_init' );
```

Why!??

But it works with a new function name!

```
function keyword2_pages_init() {
    $args = array(
      'label' => 'Keywordsx',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'keyword'),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-page',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            // 'trackbacks',
            //'custom-fields',
            //'comments',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'author',
            'page-attributes',
            )
        );
    register_post_type( 'keyword', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'keyword2_pages_init' );
```

Why!!?

Comment: That changes the issue a lot XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Custom post type "keyword" is most likely already registered. List all registered post types with this function:

`var_dump(get_post_types());`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_types

Basically the name "keyword" would be legal - from the docs:

> $post_type (string) (required) Post type. (max. 20 characters, cannot
>   contain capital letters or spaces) Default: None

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

If you are sure that the slug *keyword* is not used for something else and the error still exists it also *may be a bug in the WordPress core*. If you can find something report it.

Especially in the past with hundreds of WordPress projects I also have come across this issue one ore two times.

If the post type already exists - an answer how to de-register a post type can be found here (however it is possibly already registered for a reason by another Plugin or similar): https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3820/deregister-custom-post-types

Furthermore you should note that add_action also has a `$priority` argument. Priority may matter.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Comment: it has been used before. how can I reset??

Comment: Well if some Plugin or other part of the theme uses this keyword you maybe should NOT remove it because otherwise the Plugin will not work anymore ;-)

Anyway this is how you de-register a post-type: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3820/deregister-custom-post-types

Answer (score 0):

register_post_type( 'keyword', $args );

I think keyword is already use by theme or reserve keyword, you may change this with sum prefix like pre_keyword

If not work and change slug too.

It will solve the problem I think. I didn't test it as I am out of scope to test here.